# Executing commands based on given output

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to execute a command based on the output of another script. Say:

```
if [ -f /etc/debian_version]; then 
   DIST="Debian `cat /etc/debian_version`"
fi

OSDIST="$DIST"

# here comes the part where I'm confused

if [ $DIST = Debian 7.x (or if we're being specific here, say 7.9 for example) ]; then 
   execute_some_command
elif [ $DIST = Debian 8.x (or if we're being specific here, say 8.1 for example) ]; then 
    execute_some_other_command
fi
```

How to code something like that in sh? I'm not really sure as for what parameter or option to use for that. Thanks!

Comment: One option is `case "$DIST" in (Debian 7.*) : Do 7.x stuff;; (Debian 8.*) : Do 8.x stuff;; (*) : Which version;; esac`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try something like this;

```
case `cat /etc/debian_version` in

7.7*) echo "VERSION=7.7";
    execute_some_command; 
    ;;

7*) echo "VERSION=7";
    execute_some_command; 
    ;;

8*) echo "VERSION=8";
    execute_some_command; 
   ;;

*) echo "VERSION=NONE";
   execute_some_command; 
   ;;

esac
```